# Fancybox - using to make a before/after gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Im trying to use Fancybox to build an before/after gallery. Thats how it works:

1) The page load with a lot of thumbnails

2) When the thumb is clicked, it loads the fancybox gallery

3) When the user hover the image, it changes to the "before" state

I already did the steps 1 and 2. How can I make the 3º?

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        padding:0,
        margin:60,
        nextClick:true,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        nextEffect:'fade',
        prevEffect:'fade',
        nextSpeed :1,
        prevSpeed:1,
        afterShow : function() {
            $('.fancybox-nav').hide();
            $(".fancybox-image").hover(
            function() {$('.fancybox-next span').click();}, 
            function() {$('.fancybox-next span').click();}
            );
        }
    })
```